# InDesign crashing

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I am working on a brochure in InDesign and for some reasons, it started crashing a while ago when I try to export it as a pdf. The file is 34 pages and there are no huge images.
The only weird thing that I have used is a typeface from the Internet, (I did not convert to outlines) but I saved that typeface in a pdf previously and it exported fine.

Here the link to the file, in case you need it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dux5kejwwumrv09/Brochure_the_why.indd?dl=0

Comment: I don't have the fonts or linked images, so ... But I can tell you that the file also crashes my InDesign. Bonus info: You can't make a brochure with 34 pages in the physical world - the page count must be dividable by 4.

Comment: Well I'm not about to download a file that is reportedly crashing software. Maybe (although unlikely) the file contains a virus or malicious script... specific file examination is asking a bit much in my opinion.

Comment: This sounds like a tech support question, and these are generally off-topic here on GDSE. Perhaps best to contact Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

SOLUTION: it was a typeface license problem. I was using three typefaces that I downloaded from the Internet and I suspect that all of them had restrictions. I was able to export parts of the document to pdf, but not the whole document, this is why I was so confused. I just saved a copy of the file, outlined ALL the text in it, exported to pdf and voilà, it worked.

@Scott Virus or malicious script? LOL
@Wollf thanks, I know, I am just not sure if I want it to be a brochure or not, but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Nora, just when you are laughing at the thought of a malicious script.. one hits you. Rare, yes. Impossible No.

Comment: @Scott, you are right to be suspicious. I don't think I'll download another .indd file. I'm normally very careful, but that day I was apparently in a trustful mood. :-) But would you hesitate to download a PDF? They can also contain scripts.

Comment: @Wolff PDFs can indeed contain scripts. However, most PDF injections involve sending data somewhere - mostly javascript.. and I have software to detect unwarranted connections. Javascript, while it can be used nefariously, isn't really an "app" building language. So, I feel safer with a PDF. The problem with some other file types is that they can be much more robust scripts, in Pearl for example, which can alter the core system.

Comment: And.. just because a link appears to end with "indd" that doesn't mean it wasn't manually changed from .exe or .pkg and once you "open" or double-click the file.. the executable takes off and you're hosed. -- I simply *never* download files from unknown sources. I don't mean to cast *any* aspersions upon Nora. I certainly think she was merely seeking assistance and her link is most likely fine, but if it's already reportedly crashing software, the *cause* of those crashes, could be unknown to her and very, very, bad for a system.

Comment: People tend to be kind of laissez faire with it until they actually step in a pile of ... quicksand.

Comment: @Scott, I've been good (and lucky) and avoided malicious software for years. In the 90s I had a virus which would delete any file I double clicked! Took a while to understand what was going on and then it was too late.